# Add custom classes to magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I have custom classes 4 to 5 written in php.I want to move that to Magento as they are now.Can i do that ,And second thing how i will include if they are not in root folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to create a custom extension for this and insert each class as a model. Or optionally you can move these files to your own directory in the `./lib` directory in the root. In this directory 3th party libraries are usually included.

Then use them directly in Magento or, maybe better, have your own extension function as a sort of 'portal' to these custom libraries. It might depend on what these classes do.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have my own extension.I think the lib method is best for me.

Comment: In that case definitely, placing them there is best practice and will still allow other developers to overwrite them from local if they want/have to